# Google API autocomplete restrictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Is it possible to have the autocomplete restrict to just localities within a country?

Here is what I have currently,

```
var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
var options = {
    type: ['locality'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
};
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restrict areas with the Google Maps API, however, it is possible to set bounds which will essentially do the trick.

An introduction to bounds and how to use them:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds
https://aiocollective.com/blog/getbounds-in-google-maps-api-v3/

Answer (score 0):

you can restriction autocomplete result base on county. here you can see google official example.if you need more help then please write comment or update you Question.

and Above Ans is also perfect so you can use that one also.

[Place Autocomplete Restricted to Multiple Countries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries)